# How to set a div always in 300 pixel?

Tags: html, css

I want to set a div always in 300 pixel even if I change border, padding etc. I want to automatically subtract border, padding value from that 300px. How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[LIVE DEMO](http://codepen.io/elad2412/pen/etHzp)

when you add box-sizing:border-box the calculation includes the padding and borders

```
.class {
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box; /* firefox - from the 29 version - no need the prefix */
   box-sizing: border-box; /* others */
   width: 300px;
   padding: 10px;
   border: solid 1px black;
}
```

Here is a post about old box model and how to update to the new border-box model:
[Bye Bye Box Model](https://coderwall.com/p/-jeysw)

Browser Support is very Good as you can see here - [Can I Use Border-box](http://caniuse.com/css3-boxsizing)

(In the next monthes you can drop -moz-box-sizing, the firefox 29 version support it as well with no prefix.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [box-sizing](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/):

```
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
```

Answer (score -2):

My suggestion would be to wrap this in an enclosing div, which has max-width of 300px; and overflow: hidden;

```
div {
    max-width: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

That way, the content inside your div would at least be as dynamic as possible, while the enclosing div would protect the rest of your content.

Comment: Scratch this, use @Elad's Solution it's much cleaner - I just learned something new!

Comment: But this doesnt set the width of the box including padding and border to 300, but instead cuts of everything bigger.

Comment: True, fair enough, use Elad's solution.